# Refactor filters with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

The problem I have is that I want to implement filtering in an application in a nice way, using EntityFramework 5, over Asp.net MVC 4.

The filters are provider by a json string like this:

```
filter  
[   {"type":"string","value":"o","field":"name"},
    {"type":"list","value":[1,2,5],"field":"type"},
    {"type":"boolean","value":true,"field":"active"},   
    {"type":"numeric","comparison":"gt","value":0,"field":"order"},
    {"type":"date","comparison":"lt","value":"11/28/2014","field":"updated_at"}
]
```

(In fact, are ExtJs grid filters string)

I implemented the filters hierarchy in this way: a `FilterBase` class and then `BooleanFilter`, `StringFilter` and `ComparisonFilterBase` that inherate from `FilterBase`, and then `DateFilter` and `NumericFilter`

The filter base looks like this:

```
public abstract class FilterBase
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Filter Base Class
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The value type</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T2">The entity property's type</typeparam>
public abstract class FilterBase<T,T2>:FilterBase
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply the filter
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">The query main type, for instance, User if we are filtering users</typeparam>
    /// <param name="query">The query over to make the filter</param>
    /// <param name="field">A function that retrieves the main property's value</param>
    /// <returns>The new Query</returns>
    public abstract IQueryable<T1> Apply<T1>(IQueryable<T1> query, Func<T1, T2> field);
}
```

My idea is in each class to define the way the comparison in done. But for this I need to know the entity's field that is goin to be filtered. This is the reason of `field` parameter of the `Apply` method. For instance:

```
foreach (var filterBase in filters)
{
    switch (filterBase.Field.ToLower())
    {
        case "name":
            query = ((StringFilter)filterBase).Apply(query, u => u.UserFirstName);
            break;
        case "lastname":
            query = ((StringFilter) filterBase).Apply(query, u => u.UserLastName);
            break;
        case "login":
            query = ((StringFilter)filterBase).Apply(query, u => u.UserLogin);
            break;
        case "role":
            query = ((StringFilter)filterBase).Apply(query, u => u.UserRole.Name);
            break;
        case "email":
            query = ((StringFilter)filterBase).Apply(query, u => u.UserEmail);
            break;
        case "active":
            query = ((BooleanFilter)filterBase).Apply(query, u => u.Active);
            break;
    }
}
```

For instance, this could be the `NumericFilter` class:

```
public class NumericFilter : ComparisonFilterBase<float, float>
{
    public override IQueryable<T1> Apply<T1>(IQueryable<T1> query, Func<T1, float> field)
    {
        switch (Comparison)
        {
            case Comparison.GreaterThan:
                return query.Where(t => field(t) > Value);
            case Comparison.LowerThan:
                return query.Where(t => field(t) < Value);
            case Comparison.Equals:
                return query.Where(t => field(t) == Value); 
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that Linq to Entities does not works with the evaluation of the Function `field`. I know that for instace this query works: `query = query.Where(t => t.Age > Value);`, the only problems is that for the `ExpressionTree` the `field` parameter is a function, and not an object access part.

What can I do for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. Just use `Expression<Func<T, Type>>` instead of `Func<T,Type>`.
Something like this:

```
   public static IQueryable<T1> Apply<T1, TField>(IQueryable<T1> query, Expression<Func<T1, TField>> field, TField value, Comparison compare)
    {
        ExpressionType expressionType;
        ConstantExpression searchValue = Expression.Constant(value);
        ParameterExpression parameter = field.Parameters.First();
        Expression body;
        if (!Enum.TryParse(Enum.GetName(typeof(Comparison),compare), true, out expressionType)) 
        {
            //probably string: StartsWith, EndsWith, Contains
            MethodInfo stringMethod = GetStringMethodInfo(compare);
            body = Expression.Call(field.Body, stringMethod, searchValue);
        }
        else
        {
            body = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, field, searchValue);
        }
        Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, bool>>(body, parameter);
        return query.Where(predicate);
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetStringMethodInfo(Comparison comparer)
    {
        string methodName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Comparison), comparer);
        return
            typeof(string).GetMethods()
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.Equals(methodName) && m.GetParameters().Count() == 1);
    }

    public enum Comparison
    {
        GreaterThan = ExpressionType.GreaterThan,

        GreaterThanOrEqual = ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual,

        LessThan = ExpressionType.LessThan,

        LessThanOrEqual = ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual,

        Equals = ExpressionType.Equal,

        NotEqual = ExpressionType.NotEqual,

        StartsWith,

        EndsWith,

        Contains
    }
```

Edit: Bugfix in code according to comment

Comment: Hi and thanks for the anwser, it seems to be in the right direction. I used the abouve idea in my code, but I get this error while creating the body in the line `Expression.Call(field, stringMethod, searchValue);`.... the error: `Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Func``2`. It seems that it tries to evaluate the string method in a function, and not in the body of the function. What do you think?

Comment: I found the solution: to use `field.Body` and, other error was in the parameter, in the field expression had a name and the one we create other name, for solving this: `ParameterExpression parameter = field.Parameters.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I am sorry, i will update the code accordingly. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just for showing the final solution, maybe it helps to some others. This is based on the acepted answer from `:user3411327`. This is the final string filter `Apply` method the `Value` field is inherethed from the base filter class.

```
        public override IQueryable<T1> Apply<T1>(IQueryable<T1> query, Expression<Func<T1, string>> field)
        {   
            //create the constant expression for the value
            ConstantExpression searchValue = Expression.Constant(Value);
            //create the expression for the parameter

//            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T1), "t");
            ParameterExpression parameter = field.Parameters.FirstOrDefault();

            //create the body -> it is calling the method contains from the field in the field expression, and the value in searchValue
            MethodInfo stringMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name.Equals("Contains") && m.GetParameters().Count() == 1);
            Expression body = Expression.Call(field.Body, stringMethod, searchValue);

            //create the final predicate
            Expression<Func<T1, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, bool>>(body, parameter);
            return query.Where(predicate);
        }
```